# Using MFCC coefficients for simple voice activity detection

Tags: signal-processing, mfcc

Since MFCC coefficients stores information about amplitudes for bands of frequencies (that depends on used filter bank), how can those coefficient be used for voice activity detection?

Would it be sufficient to use this coefficients to perform further energy calculaction and make decisions with them?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1)Since MFCC coefficients stores information about amplitudes for bands of frequencies (that depends on used filter bank), how can those coefficient be used for voice activity detection?
      Answer:-As MFCC coefficients stores information about amplitudes for bands of frequencies, different people have different frequencies for utterance for same sentence. The bands of spoken words are compared with database bands frequencies and person is identified.

Question 2)Would it be sufficient to use this coefficients to perform further energy calculaction and make decisions with them?
    answer:-yes it would be sufficient to perform further energy calculation , but along with MFCC if you add LPC and other features it will give you better decision.